# What is the name of the exception indicating a primary key constrain violation?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception

I want to write a function which inserts a random UUID into a table. The function should return the UUID after successfully inserting the UUID. In case of a primary key collision I want the function to try another UUID until it succeeds.

What I have till now:

```
create or replace 
function new_object_id return raw is
  v_oid RAW(16);
begin
<<next_uuid>>
  v_oid := random_uuid();
  insert into object (object_id) values (v_oid);
  commit;
  exception
    when ?primary_key_constrain_failure? then goto next_uuid
  end;
  return v_oid;
end new_object_id;
```

But I can not figure out the right name for the exception, which occurs when the primary key constrain is violated. Does anybody know?

**Update**

I tried `dup_val_on_index` but I have still a problem with the loop:

```
create or replace 
function new_object_id return raw is
  v_oid RAW(16);
begin
<<next_uuid>>
  v_oid := random_uuid();
  insert into object (object_id) values (v_oid);
  commit;
  return (v_oid);
exception
  when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then goto next_uuid;
end new_object_id;
```

When I compile this I get the error:

```
Error(11,30): PLS-00375: illegal GOTO statement; this GOTO cannot branch to label 'NEXT_UUID'
```

Comment: Why don't you do one on purpose and read the error message?

Comment: @DanBracuk It takes some time until UUID gets its first collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/named_system.php) it is `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`.

Full working test:

```
create table x
( y number(15,0)
, constraint x_pk primary key (y)
)
;

begin
  insert into x (y) values (1);
exception
  when dup_val_on_index
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('ARGH!!!');
end;
```

For part 2, use an encapsulating `begin ... end` block:

```
begin
  <<test>>
  begin
    insert into x values (1);
    exception
      when dup_val_on_index then goto test; -- I know, a loop, but it is for the demo
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks but how about the loop?

Comment: ["A GOTO statement cannot branch into an exception handler. Also, a GOTO statement cannot branch from an exception handler into the current block."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why my version of the goto differs from the version with the inner begin, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Now it compiles:

```
create or replace 
function new_object_id return raw is
  v_oid RAW(16);
begin
<<next_uuid>>
  begin
    v_oid := random_uuid();
    insert into object (object_id) values (v_oid);
    commit;
    return (v_oid);
  exception
    when dup_val_on_index then goto next_uuid;
  end;
end new_object_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this using a LOOP try:

```
create or replace function new_object_id return raw is
  v_oid RAW(16);
begin
  LOOP
    begin
      v_oid := random_uuid();
      insert into object (object_id) values (v_oid);
      EXIT;
    exception
      when dup_val_on_index then 
        NULL;  -- do nothing, roll around to top of LOOP again
    end;
  END LOOP;

  commit;

  return (v_oid);
end new_object_id;
```

Share and enjoy.